# Why is yasm generating incorrect debugging information?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, x86-64, yasm

I have an x86_64 assembly program I'm trying to debug on Linux, but when I try to use `gdb`, it skips around randomly and loops through the same couple instructions or repeats instructions. It also seems to loop through different instructions depending on where I set a breakpoint.

I tried researching this problem online, and I saw a number of people having this same issue with C++ when compilers were optimizing too aggressively and generating incorrect debugging information. I didn't see anything about assembly, but I believe `yasm` might be the problem here as well.

Here's my Makefile.

```
myprog : myprog.o
    gcc -static -fdwarf2-cfi-asm myprog.o -o myprog
myprog.o : myprog.asm
    yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2 myprog.asm -o myprog.o
```

Note that I'm statically linking because I can't get dynamic linking to work. I might ask a separate question about that in the future.

And here's more or less what the `gdb` session looks like.

```
...
(gdb)@ n
65  call findrepl
(gdb)@ n
73  mov rdi, str3
(gdb)@ n
75  call findrepl
(gdb)@ n
75  call findrepl
(gdb)@ n
65  call findrepl
...
```

Using `s`, `si`, or `ni` all do the same as `n` shown above. I haven't had this issue with my previous assembly programs. Sometimes `gdb` will say that I've executed something like `xor eax, eax` but then show the output from a call I made to `printf`.

I'm relatively new to assembly programming and `gdb`, so in the back of my mind I wonder if this is my fault. Is there a way to fix this? I would also like to know if there are any workarounds, as I can't seem to debug it without using `gdb`.

Comment: One YASM source line corresponds to 0 or 1 asm instructions.  (Except for macros).  One C/C++ source line corresponds to potentially many *non-contiguous* asm instructions.  The "skipping around" effect is totally unrelated to C/C++ compilers where there's a real problem of how to emit debug info.  (e.g. compile something complicated on https://godbolt.org/ and notice that the source line <-> asm instruction colour coding is non-trivial, unless you leave optimization disabled).  Even YASM macros produce contiguous blocks of asm instructions.

Comment: I haven't had problems with YASM `-gdwarf2`, only with NASM `-g -Fdwarf` where that sometimes breaks `objdump -d`.  I link with `ld` or with `gcc`, but I don't use any extra GCC options like `-fdwarf2-cfi-asm`.  Although `-f` options are code-gen so probably have no effect when not turning C into asm, just linking.

Comment: I actually have no idea why I've been using `-fdwarf2-cfi-asm`. I think I started using it when I was having linking issues and it magically made some error message go away. I vaguely remember reading it in another Stack Overflow post and trying it out. I think you're right, though, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I discovered the '-tui' option for gdb and the 'layout asm' command. There's probably a better way to do this, but here's basically what you type in to make it work:

```
[user@comp ~/prog/]$ gdb -tui myprog
(gdb)@ layout asm
(gdb)@ break main
(gdb)@ run
```

And then you can go wild. By default, it's disassembled into AT&T notation. You can check which notation it's currently displaying with `show disassembly-flavor`. You can change it with `set disassembly-flavor intel` or `set disassembly-flavor att`.

For more information, run `help tui`, `help layout`, or `help set disassembly-flavor` in `gdb`.

Comment: `layout asm` or (my preference for debugging asm) `layout reg` work even if you don't *start* GDB in TUI mode.  They enter TUI mode; you can leave with `tui disab`.  See also the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info